# Call validate field function in NetSuite on particular field event

Tags: javascript, netsuite

I am trying to call one function on validate field function in NetSuite.

While calling method on validate field function it will check all the fields present on form and call same method numbers of times. Its hamper a performance.

I want to call this method on a particular field not on each and every field.
Please help

Answer (score 6):

The validateField function will be fired for each field, typically when the cursor leaves the field (similar to onBlur).  If you want to validate data for only one field, your validateField() function needs to check for the field that you want to validate.

```
function validateField(type, name, lineNumber) {
    if (name === 'custentity_some_field') {
        // Your validation logic goes here.
        return true;
    }
}
```

You can also check `type` to see if it's a field on a line item and `lineNumber` will tell you which line item that field is being validated.

Comment: +1 for this answer. Once you assign a function to any of the field events (Field Changed, Validate Field, Post Sourcing), that function will get called any time any field on the form changes. The function that gets called should simply inspect which field changed and route the logic accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Mike for the feedback. I have already written code as suggested by you. It did not solve my problem. My problem here is, I dont want to fire validateField() function on each and every field. Its should be fired only on my custom entity field. Not on every fields. Plz help on this.

Comment: Mike's answer is correct. There is no standard API to do what you want. In normal practice you shouldn't notice any performance issue with validating  only one of a hundred fields. If you are having a performance issue you should post your code and maybe we can help with that.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the case, using a workflow on edit/after field edit may simplify your solution.

Within workflows, you'll specify:

1. Record Type
2. Context
3. Function
4. Action

Goodluck!

Comment: how will workflow help if field data is invalid? from UI you have a chance that user can correct the invalid input on being alerted

Comment: Apologies.  I believe I misunderstood what you were looking for - I believe Mike Robbins has provided the best answer, above.